# How can I conditionally return a result with many permutation and combination of truthy variables?

Tags: javascript, data-structures

I have a condition where I am hoping to get `true`/`false` value of variables. Based on these values, I want to run a `if` statement. The problem is these variables need to be `true` individually or they can be `true` in numerous combinations. Similar to Permutation and Combination where there could be various situations.

```
if (a || b || c || (a && b) || (b && c) || (a && c)) || (a && b && c) {
 return true; //for example
}
```

How can I efficiently achieve this in JavaScript?

Comment: By the sound of your question it seems like you might have more than just 3 variables and can have N variables? If that's the case I'm guessing you'd be working with an array, which in that case you can loop over your elements and check if there are at least two values which are `true`. Based on your description, your if-statement should be `(a || b || c) && ((a && b) || ...)` which simplifies to `(a && b) || ...`

Comment: just create separate variables, f.e.: `const firstCondition = a || b || c; const secondCondition = a && b || a && c || b && c;`

Comment: @NickParsons that's right there could be N variables.

Comment: logically, that expression is the same as this. `if(a || b || c) return true`

Comment: @VinodLiyanage Not really, cause individually the variables can be true. Also in combinations they can be true. It is like a Filter on a product page where one option is applied and then second option is selected which filters the products with AND logic with both options true.

Comment: if `a || b || c` is not true then none of the other combinations can be true either

Comment: It feels like you may have over simplified your question or you're really asking about something else and this is the way you have decided to solve that problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The problem is these variables need to be `true` individually or they
> can be true in numerous combinations

For this, we can just check if they are true in individually, because if none of them are true, then they cannot be true in combination. ie: `a && b` can not be `true` if `a` is `false` and `b` is `false`:

```js
if (a || b || c) {
  return true;
}
```

Since one of these variables being `true` is your "minimum" requirement for returning `true` from your if-statement, we just need to check these, because if all of them happen to be `false` then none of the combinations can yield a true value (`false && false` is always `false`), but if at least one of them happens to be `true`, then we've met the condition for where the variable needs to be individually `true` and so no more checking is required.

A more general approach to this would be to use an if-statement with a for loop and an array, or use a method like [`.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) or [`.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to check that at least one variable is `true`:

```js
function condCheck(...vars) {
  return vars.includes(true);
}

const a = false;
const b = true;
const c = false;
const res = condCheck(a, b, c);
console.log(res); // true;
```